# Deleting iOS app completely

Tags: ios, applications

Does native iOS app uninstaller really remove all the data and footprints from the device, or should a person use some app cleaners like on OS X. I am wondering if leftovers cause any decrease in speed over time.

Comment: @nohillside It is a duplicate, yes, but no answers explain what is going on behind the scenes. It just proposes the common way of uninstalling apps, but we know that many official uninstallers leave some leftovers on devices - not uninstalling 100%. This is what i would like to suggest here.

Comment: It deletes the app and all its data stored on the phone. So basically pressing the icon and then the X *is* the uninstaller/app cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I use many different devices in my everyday life (ios, os x, windows, linux, android) and have really bad experience with some software leaving data folders, temporary folders, register keys,... etc on my device after uninstall. Specially on Windows.To me this is not a complete uninstall and it bugs me that they promote something that is not true.

Comment: iOS works differently :-)